# Como utilizar o interceptor no Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Sou iniciante, e no projeto em que estou desenvolvendo eu utilizei o interceptor para bloquear acesso a outros recursos caso o usuário não esteja logado na sessão.

Por exemplo: se o usuário não efetuou o login, ele não consegue acessar a pagina principal da aplicação!

Até esse momento, tudo bem!

Mas aí eu pensei em utilizar o interceptor de forma "inversa", ou seja, caso o usuário já esteja logado na sessão, ele não pode acessar a pagina de login/cadastro novamente antes que faça o logout.

É possível fazer isso com o interceptor?

**Meu interceptor:**

```
@Component
public class AutorizadorInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
       String uri = request.getRequestURI();
       if( uri.endsWith("login") || uri.endsWith("cadastro") || uri.endsWith("/") || uri.endsWith("css")){
           return true;
       } 


       if(request.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null) { 
           return true;
       }

       response.sendRedirect("login");
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, sugiro usar a configuração padrão do `Spring Security` extendendo a classe *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*. Da uma olhada nesse tutorial do link abaixo, ele é bem completo:

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() // aqui vc colocar teus CSS, JS            
            .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Fonte:

> https://blog.algaworks.com/spring-security/